# Where do I put a repository file from github for python?

Tags: python, key, repository, listener

I'm trying to use the keyboard master repository for a program I'm making in python. where do I put it?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "keyboard master repository"?

Comment: It's a repository that allows python to detect keypresses, but I don't know where to put it or how to apply it to my program.

Comment: if it is a python module - you can install it in your environment